# Package part debugging is not supported - SSIS error

Tags: ssis

I got this error message when running SSIS. It support to be a `play` icon from what I watch in the tutorial. But mine is a `start` button.

```
Package part debugging is not supported.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to debug your "[Package Part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/reuse-control-flow-across-packages-by-using-control-flow-package-parts?view=sql-server-ver15)"

If you open your main package (Package.dtsx in your screen shot), you should be able to debug it.

[image]

The Debug Menu -> Start Debugging / Start button is the one for debugging

[image]

[image]

Good luck